# Pathfinding algorithm to walk on all grids

Tags: path-finding

Given a 4x4 gridboard (as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD2XI.png)

I need to:
1. Select any one of the 16 grids to use as starting point
2. From the starting point, move one grid at a time, and walk on the other 15 grids once without repeating

Example of the pathfinding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6lBt.png
Highlighted red grid is the start point
Highlighted green grid is the end point

Comment: We don't do homework.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework... you might want to have a look at the eularian path/circuit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) problem.

Comment: Not homework. But something I would need to create a spawning algorithm for my game. I have only heard and learnt about A* myself, so I have no idea what term is given to this kind of path finding.